# PHP get time period by timestamp

Tags: php, date, time

How can I get the time period (day, week, month) by a given timestamp? I do not want the date. I want the next time period based on the amount of seconds.

Is there a PHP native function for that?

Example:

`$period = getTimeperiod( 15638400 );`

My attempt: I could check and count the seconds:

```
if x <= 60 => min
if x <= 60*60 => hour
if x <= 60*60*24 => day
...
```

Edit:

Time period means either minute, hour, day, week, ... as stated above... ?! So all I want is the corresponding time period for a timestamp.

Example: (`day = 86400 secs`) then a timestamp with `getTimeperiod( 85000 )` should be "day".

Comment: You probably mean "number of seconds" instead of timestamp, is that right?

Comment: Are you looking for how many time units has passed since UNIX Epoch (1970-01-01)?

Comment: How do you define "time period" exactly? This is not very clear, but forms the basis of your question.

Comment: time period is not a timestamp, it's time in second (not relative to any epoch as in timestamp). You might want to google for fuzzy time or relative time (2 days ago)

Comment: Why did you downvote? The definition of time period is right in the text: `time period (day, week, month)`. Relative time is a good hint.

Comment: So what you have is not a *timestamp* (that has a different meaning), but is just a number of *elapsed seconds*? Then what's wrong with the solution you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it that way:

```
  /*
  seconds     0
  minutes     1
  hours       2
  days        3
  week        4
  month       5
  year        6
  decade      7
  century     8
  millenium   9
  */

  $arTimes = array(
     0 => 1,
     1 => 60,
     2 => 60*60,
     3 => 60*60*24,
     4 => 60*60*24*7,
     5 => 60*60*24*7*4,
     6 => 60*60*24*7*4*12,
     7 => 60*60*24*7*4*12*10,
     8 => 60*60*24*7*4*12*10*10,
     9 => 60*60*24*7*4*12*10*10*10
  );

  $nDiff = strtotime( $nTo ) - strtotime( $nFrom );

  switch( $nDiff )
  {
     // check difference and time period
     case $nDiff <= $arTimes[ 1 ]:
        $nGranularity = 0;
        break;
     ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for something like the class DateInterval ...

It is part of PHP since 5.3.0 and has a static function called createFromDateString() where you can set up a DateInterval from a string like "3600 seconds". From this object you then can get the day, month, year and so on.

Take a look at this page:
http://www.php.net/manual/de/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php

Answer (score 0):

But is this on the right path returning an interval object (period)? Cred to @SimonSimCity for pointing out DateInterval. If you guide me I could improve the answer.

```
<?php 
$timestamp = 15638400;
echo "The timestamp $timestamp is " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 15638400) . "<br \>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r  (DateInterval::createFromDateString(date("Y \\y\\e\\a\\r\\s m \\m\\o\\n\\t\\h\\s d \\d\\a\\y\\s\\ H \\h\\o\\u\\r\\s i \\m\\i\\n\\u\\t\\e\\s s \\s\\e\\c\\o\\n\\d\\s", 15638400 ) ) );
echo "</pre>"
?>
```

Outputting

```
The timestamp 15638400 is 1970-07-01 00:00:00
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 1970
    [m] => 7
    [d] => 1
    [h] => 0
    [i] => 0
    [s] => 0
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 0
)
```